# Rails Migrations: How to split one table into two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have a database with the following schema:

```
[ Region ] 1 --- * [ District ] 1 --- * [ Location ]
```

I would like to split the middle table into two tables as follows:

```
[ Region ] 1 --- * [ District ] 1 --- * [ Area ] 1 --- * [ Location ]
```

...leaving some fields (and their values) in the original District table while transferring other columns (and their values) into the newly-created Area table.

Is there a standard/clean way to do this in a rails migration (preferably without the use of raw SQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could do this in 2 steps:

## **First step**

Write a migration that creates the **Area** table and its columns.
In this migration write some Ruby code to populate the table with data from **District**.

## **Second step**

Write a migration that changes the **District** table, for example one that drops unwanted columns from District.

At this point running the migrations should get you what you want without having to use SQL.

Hope it helps ! : )

Comment: Accepting as correct answer. Ended up breaking it down into multiple steps.